# How to UI test a SwiftUI View that is reused

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, uitest

It is sometimes useful to navigate to a child View from multiple links, initializing the child View differently in each navigationLink. Since the same child View is being used it would be convenient to have a single XCTestCase class that tested the child View's UI features. I think this requires me to automatically re-run the XCTestCaseClass while varying the class's properties for each run. It isn’t obvious how to do this.

The minimum example is shown below. The project was named `UITestWithPropertyVariables`. The `ContentView` (left) has a navigation link labeled "One Greeting" and a second link labeled "Three Greetings". An example of "Three Greetings" display is shown on the right.  Both links call the same child View, named `HelloWorld`. This View has a `greetings` property indicating how many times “Hello World” should be displayed. This property is set to 1 in the first link and to 3 in the second link.

**Screen Shot**

￼[image: ContentView and single example of HelloWorld View]

Of course, I could write two different UITestCase classes that have the `greetings` property hard coded, as shown below under **Sample UITest**. That would mean duplicating the test code. In this minimum example the test code only counts the number of Text Views, which isn't much of a burden. But a real world app would have extensive testing of the child view and duplicating that test logic seems inefficient and hard to maintain. Is there a better way?

**ContentView**

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                
                // First link to HelloWorld
                NavigationLink(
                    "One Greeting",
                    destination: HelloWorld( greetings: 1 ) )
                Spacer()
                
                // Second link to HelloWorld
                NavigationLink(
                    "Three Greetings",
                    destination: HelloWorld( greetings: 3) )
                Spacer()
            }
            .padding()
            .navigationTitle("Test Of Reused Scenes")
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

**HelloWorld**

```
import SwiftUI

struct HelloWorld: View {
    var greetings = 1
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach( 0 ..< greetings )
            {   greeting in
                Text( "Hello World #\(greeting + 1)")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ReusableHelloWorld_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static let numberGreetings = 3
    static var previews: some View {
        HelloWorld( greetings: numberGreetings )
    }
}
```

**Sample UITest** (but having hard-coded, non-varying properties)

```
import XCTest

final class UITestWithPropertyVariables: XCTestCase {

    // Hard-coded properties (those that I'd like to vary automatically in UITests)
    let navigationText = "Three Greetings"
    let expectedGreetings = 3
    
    // non-varying properties
    let app = XCUIApplication()
    
    override func setUpWithError() throws {
        app.launch()
        continueAfterFailure = false
    }

    func testExample() throws {
        // navigate to a scene based on the varying properties
        let navigationButton =
            app.buttons[ navigationText ]
        XCTAssert( navigationButton.isHittable )
        navigationButton.tap()
        
        // check that the greeting appears the expected number of times,
        // again basing the test on the varying properties
        let helloWorldPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "label beginswith 'Hello World'")
        let greetingTexts =
            app.staticTexts.matching( helloWorldPredicate )
        XCTAssert( greetingTexts.count == expectedGreetings )
    }
}
```